# jQuery won't translate 401 errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-error

this is an annoying one.
When using jquery's GET ajax call from **localhost** to a server that supports CORS, 
an unauthorized call (401) is not being passed as a 401 status but rather as a 0 status error, although the browser's dev tools console **does** present it as 401 Unauthorized:

[image]

And the ajax status code is 0, as mentioned:
[image]
Any ideas why or how to fix it (in case of 401 I obviously want to redirect the user to log in)...

Answer (score 0):

you can try this global function of jQuery [ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function( event, jqxhr, settings, exception ) {
    if ( jqxhr.status== 401 ) {
        // redirect to login
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. For some reason the browser/jquery keep parsing incorrectly the error. Chrome status - 0, firefox 404.
It might be a localhost issue or a Mac (OS X 10.9).

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders() and jqxhr.statusCode()?

Answer (score 0):

Try this  tool : [All-Control-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) , it will allow you to bypass chromes pesky CORS issues. I have the same issue with a 0 instead of a 401.